# Assuming: what am I doing wrong?

Tags: assumptions

Why doesn't this simple line work?

```
Assuming[Element[#, Reals] & /@ {x}, Reduce[x^4 == 1]]
(* x==-1||x==-I||x==I||x==1 *)
```

I'm trying to do something a little bit complicated, and it really comes down to understanding why this doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Another question along these lines:

Say I want to calculate the eigenvalues of a symbolic matrix:

mat = {{a, b, c}, {e, f, g}, {h, i, j}};

Eigenvalues[mat]

(Root[c f h-b g h-c e i+a g i+b e j-a f j+(-b e+a f-c h-g i+a j+f j) #1+(-a-f-j) #1^2+#1^3&,1]
Root[c f h-b g h-c e i+a g i+b e j-a f j+(-b e+a f-c h-g i+a j+f j) #1+(-a-f-j) #1^2+#1^3&,2]
Root[c f h-b g h-c e i+a g i+b e j-a f j+(-b e+a f-c h-g i+a j+f j) #1+(-a-f-j) #1^2+#1^3&,3]

)

I get an output in a split second. Now let's say I want to restrict all variables to the real numbers:

list2 = Flatten[mat];

FullSimplify[Eigenvalues[mat], 
  Assumptions -> {Element[#, Reals] & /@ list2}]

and this last command doesn't finish evaluating after a very long time. Any intuition on what's going on here? Probably something to do with the evaluation of the cubic roots.

Comment: Reduce[x^4 == 1, x, Reals]

Comment: There were several similar questions in the past, perhaps others will post more links.  In general, `Assuming` will only affect functions that have the `Assumptions` option.  `Reduce` is not one of these.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

bill s shows the proper way to achieve what you seek, but to answer your question "Why doesn't this simple line work?", consider this:  Your line forces `x` to be `Real`, and *THEN* seeks to reduce the quartic equation.  It is perfectly acceptable, then, for the solutions to be imaginary.

To see a silly example, consider this:

```
Assuming[x == 2, Solve[x^2 == 9, x]]
```

(*
{{x -> -3}, {x -> 3}}
*)

Comment: A humble suggestion:  Don't write phrases such as "what am I doing wrong?" in a title.  Such phrases are unhelpful as they neither describe the problem nor improve future searches.  Try:  "Assuming does not constrain Reduce" or something like that.

Comment: Well thanks for your answer and suggestion.Very helpful.

Comment: I added a similar question. I didn't think I should start a new question for it, and it seems closely related to the original one.

Comment: I think that's a bad idea too... It clogs the site, and renders all the contributions to this problem harder to find.  Why not just fix the problem here and be done with it?